# Computing the density of the smallest and second smallest values

Tags: probability, order-statistics

Let $X_i$ be a sequence of $n$ iid real valued random variables with distribution $F$ and density $f$ with respect to lebesgue measure. Compute the density function of the two smallest values in a sample of size $n$.

**My attempt**

Plan to compute the distribution function and then differentiate this to obtain the density function.

$$\mathbb P(X_{(1)} \leq t_1, X_{(2)} \leq t_2) = \mathbb P(X_{(1)} \leq \min\{t_1, t_2\})$$

since in the case that $t_1 \leq t_2$, the event $\{X_{(1)} \leq t_1, X_{(2)} \leq t_2\}$ is equivalent to the event $\{X_{(1)} \leq t_1\}$ and in the case that $t_1 > t_2$ the event is equivalent to $\{X_{(1)} \leq t_2\}$.

Now, differentiating $\mathbb P(X_{(1)} \leq \min\{t_1, t_2\})$ with respect to $t_1$ and $t_2$ is $0$ when $t_1 \neq t_2$, but this can't be correct since I expect the density to be $0$ only when $t_2 < t_1$.

Where did I make an incorrect assumption?

Comment: Don't reinvent the wheel: apply formulas for $f_{X_{(r)}}(x)$ you will find [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_statistic).

Comment: I should have mentioned, I know I can reference well known results on the density of the joint of all order statistics and then integrate out the unwanted variables, but I'm trying to understand my erorr

Comment: You cannot say $$\mathbb P(X_{(1)} \leq t_1, X_{(2)} \leq t_2) = \mathbb P(X_{(1)} \leq \min\{t_1, t_2\})$$ I personally would first find the conditional distribution of $X_{(2)}$ given $X_{(1)}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your error is that you cannot say that the events

$E_1:=(X_{(1)} \leq t_1, X_{(2)} \leq t_2)$ and $E_2:=(X_{(1)} \leq \min\{t_1, t_2\})$ are the same.

You can just say that $E_1 \subset E_2$ (meaning $E_1 \implies E_2$), but $E_2$ cannot imply $E_1$ ; therefore you haven't the corresponding equality of probabilities.